# Mongo - aggregate with multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have collection that hold user's purchases into stores and the likes and dislikes he got for this purchase from his friends. the collection fields looks like that:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543e43cea7c481c4820ab014"),
    "user" : "542ea90fbb1e37b09f660980",
    "product" : "543e43cea7c481c4820ab013",
    "store" : "542e6fb1a2a8a7a071490555",
    "status" : "active",
    "dislikes" : 1,
    "likes" : 3,
    "addedAt" : ISODate("2014-10-15T09:52:14.661Z")
}
```

Now, I want to get the following summaries:

1. Get the diff of (likes - dislikes) for user X
2. Get the diff of (likes - dislikes) for user X into store Y
3. Get the diff of (likes - dislikes) for user X into store Y and product Z

For #1, i made:

```
[
   {$group: {_id: '$user', rankDiff: {$sum: {$subtract: ['$likes', '$dislikes']}}}},
   {$match : { _id: 'X'}}
],
```

I'm getting proper results:

> [
> {
> "_id" : "542ea90fbb1e37b09f660980",
> "rankDiff" : 2
> } ]

But when i'm trying to get #2 by:

```
[
   {$group: {_id: '$user', rankDiff: {$sum: {$subtract: ['$likes', '$dislikes']}}}},
   {$match : { _id: 'X'}, store: 'Y'}
],
```

Or to get #3 by:

```
[
   {$group: {_id: '$user', rankDiff: {$sum: {$subtract: ['$likes', '$dislikes']}}}},
   {$match : { _id: 'X'}, store: 'Y', product: 'Z'}
],
```

No results in return.

Is someone can please help me with that? what I'm doing wrong?

p.s. did all by Mongoose but also directly with Robomongo via my MongoDB instance

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the quesry syntax should be:

```
[
   {$match : { user: 'X', store: 'Y', product: 'Z'},
   {$group: {_id: '$user', rankDiff: {$sum: {$subtract: ['$likes', '$dislikes']}}}}
]
```

And now its working fine.

Thanks!